# WITH RECURSIVE as second part CTE in query. Postgres

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

How I can write a query like that:

```
with t1 as 
(
select id 
from table1
),
RECURSIVE t2(
select * from t2
union
...
)
```

Currently it's not allowed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `recursive` needs to be right after the `WITH` regardless on where you put the recursive CTE:

```
with recursive t1 as 
(
  select id 
  from table1
), t2 (
  select *  
  from t2
  union
  ...
)
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I would never have thought that such a syntax